# Is there a queue of messages sent to a socket server?

Tags: c#, sockets, flutter, dart

My Flutter app connects to a c# server socket if both devices (smartphone and PC) are online.

If the server socket is offline, the Flutter app tries to connect every two seconds.

When a reconnect happens after some minutes, the connection is accepted, but data is not received at the beginning, but a lot of messages at once some seconds later.

I tried to destroy the client socket (Flutter) after a 2 seconds timeout, but this does not help.

When I restart my app, everything is working fine. What is the app restart doing, that I am missing?

```dart
Future<void> ConnectToPC() async {
    //Called periodically from Timer

    String Sucess = 'Already trying to connect';

    if (!tryingToConnect) {
      try {
        print('Trying to connect to $cardIP on port $cardPort');
        tryingToConnect = true;
        ClientSocket = await Socket.connect(cardIP, int.parse(cardPort))
            .timeout(Duration(seconds: 2));
        print('Socket connected!');
        ClientSocket.listen(HandleIcomingEvents,
            onError: SocketErr, onDone: SocketClose, cancelOnError: false);
        connected = true;
        tryingToConnect = false;
        Sucess = 'Connected';
        cardstate = 'Online';

        //initiate communication, use response for initial stuff
        SendToServer("!GETREADY!\n");
        //Await pong within the specified timeout
        PongReceived = DateTime.now();
        //Start send and check !PING! periodically
        SetPingTimer('ON');
      } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
        print('Timeout');
        tryingToConnect = false;
        Sucess = 'Connection failed';
        if (ClientSocket!=null) ClientSocket.destroy();
      } on OSError {
        print('OS error');
      } on Exception catch (e) {
        print('Socket connection error $e');
        tryingToConnect = false;
        Sucess = 'Connection failed';

        WhenDisconnected();
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      StatusText = Sucess;
    });
  }

  void WhenDisconnected() {
    SetPingTimer('OFF');
    connected = false;
    cardstate = 'Not connected';
    ClientSocket.destroy();
    gotTheJo=false;
    ClientSocket=null;
  }
```

I also receive multiple "pong" on one ping being sent via
await ClientSocket.add(utf8.encode(TextInhalt));

Comment: Sockets are a very nuanced technology and its hard to get them completely right unless you spend a lot of time on them. I would suggest using a more mature technology like, signalr, web services or any number of other solutions

Comment: @TheGeneral The server is running on Windows PC as a service. The mature technology you mentioned should be available for Flutter as a package, as well as for C# via Nuget. Just a one-to-one connection is needed with some simple data exchange. Any proposal for a mature protocol?

Comment: You are specifying a stream timeout, rather that a connect timeout. If you do, in fact, want the latter, use `Socket.connect(host, port, timeout: Duration(seconds: 2))`

Comment: @RichardHeap I tried your changes, but after the server being offline the Flutter code still sends multiple pings at a time. What is the restart of the app doing that I am missing?

Comment: @ChristianDressler id just use SignalR, extremely simple to set up, and it just works

Comment: @TheGeneral The c# app is running as service with topshelf, but SignalR only available for ASP.net.

Comment: It turned out that a timer was the root cause, not the socket.connect. Delete this post or keep it?